# How can I do my data consistent in java

Tags: java

Forexample if I have address fields for different rows like

```
(Ho. #  103 street #  65 Saat meel Kalar RAWALPINDI), 
(h no. 732 St. No. 55 Mor gha RAWALPINDI),
(h# 611 St. # 57  old lalazar RAWALPINDI)
```

Then how can I make it unique like

```
(Ho. # 103 street # 65 Saat meel Kalar RAWALPINDI), 
(Ho. # 732 Street # 55 Mor gha RAWALPINDI),
(Ho. # 611 Street # 57 old lalazar RAWALPINDI)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He wants to know how to make his data persistent.

Comment: @Vipar, no he wants to make it "consistent" - just like the title says.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I thought he might have mistaken the words for each other because of lack of formatting. Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not trying to make it "unique" but, like the title says "consistent."

This is difficult to do. What you need to do is parse the data, allowing for different types of identifying strings. For example, for house, it looks like you want to accept `"Ho. #"`, `"h no."`, and `"h#"`.

Once you've parsed the data, you can store it in any fashion you want (probably in a database). Then you are free to output it in any format you wish (like your last example).

There is nothing built-in that will do this for you magically.

The pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
input = input.toLower()

house_ids = ['ho. #', 'h no.', 'h#']

p = start of string
While data left in string:
    if string_at(p) is one of house_ids:
        advance p
        house_num = number_at(p)
    // street, etc.
```

Comment: What if I don't have delimiter in the address field. How can I know which one is house# and which one is Street#.

Comment: Thankyou for the help :) I got it. Can you please help me more. 

I have country in the address fields, but some records might have abbreviations of country like

h no. 732 St. No. 55 Mor gha RAWALPINDI
h# 455 street no.4  Westridege 2 Rwp

In this Rwp is also called RAWALPINDI. So how can I do it persistent. Can I hard code all the abbreviations? Any other way?

Comment: I would have all of the abbreviations in a database, and look the country up. I don't know where you're from or how addresses work there, but there may be some national service that you can look this information up in. Heck, you may be able to replace all of this code with a call to some [webservice like the USPS provides](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm).